# Display Header in TableView

Tags: ios, header, swift3, tableview

I start to be crazy for a simple thing I cannot do: display the tabeview Header . I am using Swift 3.0 with a Dynamic Table View. In this tableview I am creating a contact directory where the user can add a list of contact.
I declare my tableview in the storyboard with Dynamic Prototype content. Programmatically I do what I need to do to have my list of contacts and my list is displaying properly in my table view.

Then I declare 1 section and the using the following method:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

            return 50.0
}
```

In the header I add a button to do some actions on my contact list:

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

```
    let frame: CGRect = tableView.frame
    let DoneBut: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: frame.size.width - 200, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50))
    DoneBut.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    DoneBut.backgroundColor = UIColor.red



    DoneBut.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    DoneBut.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue


    let headerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    headerView.addSubview(DoneBut)

    return headerView


}
```

=> Result is no Header displayed only my list. Any advices to be able to the Header ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to amend your `heightForHeaderInSection` and `viewForHeaderInSection` methods slightly. 
You have to add an override for both and also an '_' after the first parenthesis for both methods. (see below)

With this code the section headers displayed for me.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let frame: CGRect = tableView.frame
    let DoneBut: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: frame.size.width - 200, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50))
    DoneBut.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    DoneBut.backgroundColor = UIColor.red



    DoneBut.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    DoneBut.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue


    let headerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: 50))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    headerView.addSubview(DoneBut)

    return headerView
}
```